# Bootable pendrive for Windows 10 Technical Preview

Tags: windows, live-usb

I want to install Windows 10 Technical Preview. I have downloaded its .iso file. Now I want to make a flash drive bootable. How can I do that?

I already have tried these 2 options.

1. Making a bootable pendrive via `dd` command, but it's not working.

   ```
   sudo umount /dev/sdb
   sudo dd if=/path/to/windows10.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M && sync
   ```
2. I also have tried using WinUSB, but it's not working either.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
   sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-trusty.list"
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install winusb
   ```

It was just running a process showing a message that it's formatting the USB stick, but that didn't last for 20 minutes!! And I had to cancel it.

Is there any way I can make a bootable pendrive for installing Windows 10 from Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score -2):

use unetbootin!
easy, fast, with GUI, give it a try! ;)

or right click on win10 image, open with disk image mounter, and copy all to your bootable pen. make sure it's empty on either way, you can use "disks"* from ubuntu, have a look on youtube, lots of ways to do that (just look for any windows image, it's all the same) ;)

*disks: select your pendrive, unmount, click on the wheels, format, fat32 (it'll say lba initializable), then copy or use unetbootin!

Comment: Doesn't work at all!

Comment: are you sure that the .iso you downloaded is fine? may be corrupted ...
have you tried something like this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09i6ERj5cik

Comment: No my iso file is not currupted I'm sure. And the tutorial's link you posted is for making bootable stick for Windows 7 not 10.

Comment: i know, it's all the same, i have booted windows xp, 7, 8, 8.1, ubuntu, xubuntu, etc, from .iso to usb using unetbootin, and that tutotial is clear ... if it doesn't work for you, i don't know how to help, unless win10 is different than other versions of windows...